# Gap between two UItableview cells 3

Tags: ios

I have a table view whose  gap between cells are two low.
how to add gap or space between  two table view cells ?
I am using xcode to make UItableview.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri this answer covers the my second option of my answer but if he cannot replace rows with section option 1 can also work for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. In your tableview cell create transparent UIView, put it on the bottom of the cell, add autolayout constraints and set the height constraint to the height of your gap
2. Replace **numberOfSectionsInTableView** method with **numberOfRowsInSection** so each item in your array will be a section and not a row and then implement the method **heightForHeaderInSection** and return the value of the gap.

Hope it helps